# keys or list for my redis datamodel?

Tags: redis

I'm building the data model of my app and basically, for a given user, I'd like to keep a list of his/her friends and the status of each of them (if they accepted the request to be friends or if they did not yet)

I end up with several keys: (one for each friend of tom)

```
friends:tom:status:jessica => joined
friends:tom:status:stephan => joined
friends:tom:status:hubert => pending
friends:tom:status:peter => declined
```

Is that the best way to handle that or should a list be used in some other way ?

Comment: IS it for single user or multiple

Comment: @GaneshKumar it is for multiple users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use for example [hash](http://redis.io/commands#hash) structure where hash key would be `friends:tom:status`, field would represent friend name/ID and value would represent his status. Hash structure is more [memory efficient](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1010844204/redis-memory-usage) than dedicated keys in general.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an ordered set for this.

Have each status have a score associated with it, joined 1, pending 2, declined 3

```
zadd user1_friends 1 userid 1 userid 2 userid
```

then you can easily retrieve all users by category

```
zscore user1_friends 1
```

or you could split into 3 separate sets

```
sadd user1_joined userid1
sadd user1_pending userid3
```

Depending on what you want to do either will work